# How to make a grid side to side uiview responsive on storyboard using auto layout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, storyboard, ios-autolayout

im trying to make a month calendar in swift, but im strugging with an auto layout issue.

I need 7 squares side to side, and i want to make them responsive. I have tryied to set every square trailling and leading based on the preview and next square, but it wont work without setting the width (what will make it go unresponsive). Can someone help me please?

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know there's always 7 cells in a row (sounds like it, calendars are pretty stable that way), you want to set up a width relationship.

1. Set the width of the first cell to the width of the parent view ("Equal Widths"). Sounds strange at first
2. But then double-click on the resulting constraint in the Constraints Inspector to get the detailed constraint editor.
3. Set the Multiplier to "1:7"
4. Set the Constant to some small value to allow for inter-cell padding.
5. Set all the other cells to equal the width of the first cell.

Comment: You may also want to ditch AutoLayout and put the whole thing in a `UICollectionView`. It's a lot more work upfront, but you have a great deal of flexibility and power, where you can control widths, offsets, inter-cell spacing, all algorithmically. Might be useful especially when a month doesn't start in the leftmost column, or if you want to scroll through multiple months in one view.

Comment: I will read about UICollectionView. I have managed another way to make it work using your approach (1:7).  But using trailing and leading constants relative to superview (just like an absolute position)